# jQuery Use the text of an element to toggle another element that contains the same text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm extremely new to jquery and I've been struggling to create this action. Any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated.

I need a way in jquery that allows a user to click a span and toggle (i.e [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)) another div that contains the same text as the span being clicked, without having to repeat the same function for each individual span.

My example:

```
<ul>
<li class="sub">
  <div class="filter-row">
      <div class="row-section">
          <div class="row-heading">art</div>
              <span class="label studio-art">studio art</span>
              <span class="label ceramics">ceramics</span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="sub">
  <div class="filter-row">
      <div class="row-section">
          <div class="row-heading">studio art</div>
          <span class="label">Option 1</span>
          <span class="label">Option 2</span>
      </div>

      <div class="row-section">
          <div class="row-heading">ceramics</div>
          <span class="label">Option 1</span>
          <span class="label">Option 2</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

If a user were to click the span that contains "studio art",  then I want the div that contains "studio art" to ".toggle()". I do know that I could give a unique class such as ".studio-art" to the span and div that i want to connect together, such as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span.label.studio-art").click(function(){
        $(".row-section.studio-art").toggle();
    });

    $("span.label.ceramics").click(function(){
      $(".row-section.ceramics").toggle();
    });
});
```

Jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/KCRUSHER/6qLX7/

But I want to avoid doing what I have above since I may have hundreds of spans or instances like this.

So basically I'm hoping for help to create a solution that only needs the string in a span to match the string in my "row-heading" div. So that when a span is clicked the row-section div will toggle.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all other `div` elements with the same text by using jQuery's `filter` method and toggle them. You'll have to pick your class names more sensibly to make sense and easier to understand.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".row-section span").click(function(){
    var clickedText = $(this).text();
        $(".row-section").filter(function(){
            return $(this).find("div").text() === clickedText;
        }).toggle();
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6qLX7/2/

`.filter` documentation: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Thank you for the solution, this has helped me greatly. As far as class names go, do you have any suggestions. Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this, but it should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("span.label").click(function(){
    var checkText = $(this).html();
    $( ".row-section:contains('"+checkText+"')" ).each(function(index,element){
      // This checks for exact match. If you want any "containing" match, remove the if-clause
      if($(element).html() == checkText) {
        $(element).toggle();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Let me know if this helps. 
 P.S.! This function IS case-sensitive (see http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ for more details.)

Comment: This did work, thank you so much for your suggestion. But, I went with another answer since it used less lines.

Comment: Of course, everyone does it differently. I tried to keep it as simple as possible. I agree, that the solution above is more elegant :)