# Get Checkbox to toggle div based on only the string inside a checkbox's label - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to create a script to hide divs based on just the label of a "checked" checkbox. And do it without having to use a specific value, id or attribute. I was previously shown how to [do it using spans/divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583040/jquery-use-the-text-of-an-element-to-toggle-another-element-that-contains-the-sa), but checkboxes have got me stumped.

My example in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6qLX7/2/

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="filter-row">
<div class="row-section">
    <div class="row-heading">art</div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="studio art" value=".studio_art" id="studio_art" />
                <label for="studio_art">studio art</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="ceramics" value=".ceramics" id="ceramics" />
                <label for="ceramics">ceramics</label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="filter-row">
<div class="row-section">
    <div class="row-heading">studio art</div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="button" value=".option1" name="option1" id="option1" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="button" value=".option2" name="option2" id="option2" />
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="row-section ">
    <div class="row-heading">ceramics</div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="button" value=".option1" name="option1" id="option1" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="button" value=".option2" name="option2" id="option2" />
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input:checked").click(function () {
    var clickedText = $(this).text();
    $(".row-section").filter(function () {
        return $(this).find("div").text() === clickedText;
    }).toggle();
});
});
```

Comment: Your example does not match the jsfiddle

Comment: @AndrewShepherd ...yes, and that is covered in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ru8YL/1/

I've created a new selector to get the label text that accords with the checkbox: `$(this).siblings('label').text()`.

Select all checkboxes instead of the buttons you previously used: `$("input:checkbox")`.

Use the `change` event rather than `click`.

Use `.is(':checked')` to see if the checkbox is checked or not.

Send `toggle` a parameter to tell it to hide or show. This second parameter is specified in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    var clickedText = $(this).siblings('label').text();
    console.log(clickedText);
    $(".row-section").filter(function () {
        return $(this).find("div.row-heading").text() === clickedText;
    }).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").change(function () {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
    });
});
```

use `change` event instead of `click` event

Answer (score 0):

Here's my contribution. It just shows there's a large number of ways you can express the same thing using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
        var clickedText = $(this).next('label').text();
        $("fieldset:nth-child(2) .row-section").filter(function () {
            return $('.row-heading', this).text() === clickedText;
        }).toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LhuT9/1/

Compared this with Joe Frambach's answer, it differs by:

- This example uses `next` instead of `siblings`
- The filter function extracts the text using `$('.row-heading', this).text()` instead of `$(this).find("div.row-heading").text()`

Comment: Thank you for explaining it, it didn't work with my full blown prototype, but I will continue to experiment with your response.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another alternative, though it's much the same with only minor differences:

```
// selects all input elements whose type is 'checkbox':
$('input[type="checkbox"]')
// binds an anonymous function to the 'change' event:
.on('change', function(){
    // caching the this variable for later use:
    var input = this,
    // finding whether node.textContent or node.innerText is supported in the browser:
        textProp = 'textContent' in document.body ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

    // selecting the '.row-section' elements,
    $('.row-section')
    // filtering that collection:
    .filter(function(){
        // using '$.trim()' to remove leading/trailing white-space
        return $.trim($(this)
            // finding the 'div.row-heading' elements within the current '.row-section':
            .find('div.row-heading')
            // retrieving its text:
            .text())
            // comparing for strict equality:
            === 
            // finding the text of the label attached to the element
            // the benefit of this approach is that it's independent
            // of the DOM structure:
            $.trim(input.labels[0][textProp]);
    // showing if the input is checked, hiding if not:
    }).toggle(input.checked);
// triggering the change event, so the anonymous function is called on page-load:
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ru8YL/3/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLInputElement`, to see a brief introduction to the `labels` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)
- jQuery:

  - [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
  - [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).